# print kable in local function not working

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I'm trying to 'print' a `kable` within a local function, `print_header` inside a Rmarkdown document.

Here's a reproducible example - save the following as a `.Rmd` file and use `rmarkdown::render(...)` to render the `.Rmd` file

````
---
title: test
---

```{r echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
print_header <- function() {
    require(tidyverse)
    require(knitr)
    require(kableExtra)
    
    mtcars %>%
        head(5) %>%
        kable("html") %>%
        kable_styling()
        
    return(0)
}

print_header()
print("break")
mtcars %>% head(5) %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling()
```
````

The output looks like

```
test
[1] 0 [1] “break”
mpg cyl disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs  am  gear    carb
Mazda RX4   21.0    6   160 110 3.90    2.620   16.46   0   1   4   4
Mazda RX4 Wag   21.0    6   160 110 3.90    2.875   17.02   0   1   4   4
etc
```

That is, the kable in `print_header()` does not print, but the second `kable` does. Why does a kable not 'print' when inside a function in an Rmarkdown doc?

#### Edit

As a few commenters have noted, *removing `return(0)` allows for kable printing* - as far as I understand, this works because the kable object is returned to the parent environment where it is printed. Thus, as @RyanMorton has suggested, wrapping the kable as an object and returning it will also work. But I'm still interested in knowing how to **force kable printing from within the local function environment** - if this is not possible, I'd like to understand why.

Comment: try to remove the `return(0)` . In your output the [1] 0 - is the actual output from your function.

Comment: I'm not actually interested in returning the output. I'd like to know why the kable prints outside the function but not inside the function

Comment: It prints inside the function if you don't `return(0)` - so do you need the function to print the kable AND return something else? You can only return a single object (which could be a list of objects): http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#return-values

Comment: @RyanMorton - you asked `do you need the function to print the kable AND return something else?` - A: I only need to print the kable inside the function

Comment: Then remove the `return(0)`

Comment: @RyanMorton - yes, that works - but let me ask another way, how could I force kable printing from within the function? (Edited my Q)

Comment: I'd assign the output in an object and return that object: `print_header <- function() {
    require(tidyverse)
    require(knitr)
    require(kableExtra)

    t <- mtcars %>%
        head(5) %>%
        kable("html") %>%
        kable_styling()

    return(t)
}`. It's similar to how you might return an error message from a function before the function completes. You can return an object anytime in the function, but only one object gets returned.

Comment: @RyanMorton - this is essentially what happened when I deleted `return(0)`. The last evaluated object, ie the kable, was returned as an object.